# I'm not sure if my question is appropriate for SE.Politics

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I am new to politics stack exchange and I just wanted to verify whether my question is appropriate for SE.Politics or not. Its about a policy proposal. I'm genuinely trying to do research and see if the merits/issues of said proposal, I'm not trying to puch my opinions on the topic. This is what I wanted to research:

1. Have any countries/states implemented a similar policy?
2. What would the merits of such a proposal be?
3. What would the harms of such a proposal be?

Are these questions appropriate to ask on SE.Politics? If not, where should I ask?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are generally on-topic questions, e.g. questions of the first category they usually fall under the [comparative-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-politics) tag.

Be more careful with the #2 & #3. There are some questions like those too e.g. [Which are the advantages of monarchy?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/8264/which-are-the-advantages-of-monarchy) but it sometimes can become a mostly [SE user] opinion-based question, e.g. if the policy proposal is obscure or elaborate enough that few have considered and written about it "in the real world". (There's a close reason for questions that are likely to be answered primarily with [SE users'] opinions, without reference to facts, facts which in this case would be what some others' have already written about the advantages [or disadvantages] of something at least somewhat similar.)

But since you said "question" rather than question**s** in your title, also beware of asking too many questions in one (question post), as there is a close reason for that ["too broad" it used to be called, I think it was recently renamed to "needs more focus".] So yeah, you can easily (and probably should) ask 3 separate questions. But some may be obsolete in view of answers to others, e.g. answers to questions about who else did or didn't do something may already carry a fair bit of [implicit] explanation as to when an policy is considered suitable (and by whom).